# Incorrect Number of Bindings Error with SQLite

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, sqlite

A little background I am doing this in python 2.7 for the reason of Alexa Rank through SeoLib but am completely open to updating if that would help this issue or possibly solve future issues.

Now this program sorts through sites that I have in a predetermined csv that looks like the following:

```
site
00rbt.com
```

I am specifically getting the following error:

```
 File "igorPanda.py", line 84, in <module>
    update_site(site,cur_ip,cur_rank,cur_hash)
  File "igorPanda.py", line 30, in update_site
    (site))
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 9 supplied.
```

Where this error is occuring is:

```
def update_site(site,cur_ip,cur_rank,cur_hash):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('/root/Database/Sites.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    with conn:
        cursor.execute("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * from sites WHERE site = ?)",
                       (site))
        record = cursor.fetchone()
        if record[0] == 1:
            cursor.execute("UPDATE sites SET cur_ip = ?, cur_rank = ?, cur_hash = ? WHERE site = ?",
                       (cur_ip,cur_rank,cur_hash,site))
        else:
            cursor.execute("INSERT into sites values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",
                       (site,cur_ip,None,cur_rank,None,None,cur_hash,None))
```

My entire code except imports is:

```
#Updates the DB
def update_site(site,cur_ip,cur_rank,cur_hash):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('/root/Database/Sites.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    with conn:
        cursor.execute("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * from sites WHERE site = ?)",
                       (site))
        record = cursor.fetchone()
        if record[0] == 1:
            cursor.execute("UPDATE sites SET cur_ip = ?, cur_rank = ?, cur_hash = ? WHERE site = ?",
                       (cur_ip,cur_rank,cur_hash,site))
        else:
            cursor.execute("INSERT into sites values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",
                       (site,cur_ip,None,cur_rank,None,None,cur_hash,None))
#Moves CSV for Historical Savings
bashmove = "mv top.csv /root/Desktop/scripts/results-igor/top-$(date +%m-%d-%Y).csv"
#Sets file with all sites to variable
filename='/root/Desktop/scripts/sorted.csv'
#Creates hash algorithm for later use
hasher = hashlib.sha256()
sess = requests.Session()
x = datetime.datetime.now()
date = x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
regex = r"^(?:https?:)?(?:\/\/)?(?:[^@\n]+@)?(?!www\.)?([^:\/\n]+)\w*\.\b(com|org|co|be|de|br|(\w+\b))" #regex to get stripepd website no https://www. or anything afte$

df = pd.DataFrame()
df = df.append(pd.read_csv(filename), ignore_index=True)
ip = "NOT FOUND"
for i in df.index:
    #print(i)
    site = df['site'][i]
    try :
     ip = socket.gethostbyname(site)
     page = requests.get('http://' + df['site'][i], timeout=5)
     hasher.update((page.text).encode('utf-8'))
    except: #ignore errors if the site is bad
        pass
    try :
     alexa_rank = seo.get_alexa('http://{}'.format(site)) #seolib gets the alexa ranking
     #alexa_rank = None
    except:
     pass
    site = site
    cur_ip = ip
    cur_rank = alexa_rank
    cur_hash = hasher.hexdigest()
    update_site(site,cur_ip,cur_rank,cur_hash)  
    rd = call(["/root/Desktop/scripts/./rDNSlookup.sh", site, ip]) #call bash script to get reverse DNS of ip
    wi = call(["/root/Desktop/scripts/./whois.sh", site]) #call bash script to print host info
    with open('/root/Desktop/scripts/IGOR_His/'+ date + 'sites.csv', 'a') as f:
      print >> f, 'site: ',site,', ip: ',ip,', rank: ',alexa_rank, ', hash', cur_hash
shutil.copy("/root/Database/Sites.db", "/var/www/html/sites/Sites.db")
```

The table has the following columns:

```
site,cur_ip,prev_ip,cur_rank,prev_rank,play,cur_hash,prev_hash
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: use `(site,)`

**In detail:**

`cursor.execute` expects the second paramter to be an iterable.

When your code says:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * from sites WHERE site = ?)", (site))
```

Then `(site)` is not a tuple - you probably meant to convert it to a tuple by wrapping it in `()`.

So what you meant/want is:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * from sites WHERE site = ?)", (site,))
```

Notice the extra `,`!

To avoid this tuple confusion, you can also use a list:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * from sites WHERE site = ?)", [site])
```

**The issue in even more detail:**

```
cursor.execute("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * from sites WHERE site = ?)", (site))
```

is the same as:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * from sites WHERE site = ?)", site)
```

is the same (in your case) as:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * from sites WHERE site = ?)", "00rbt.com")
```

The string `00rbt.com` is used as iterable, and since it has 9 characters, you get the error:

> sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 9 supplied.

Comment: Ahh that worked thank you so much! I originally had it just as an update so I added the bits to insert if not found and that's when I was hitting the issue

Answer (score 1):

You get this error, because here:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * from sites WHERE site = ?)", (site))
```

you should pass, as the 2nd argumnet of `execute()` a tuple and not just a string. 
This is easily fixed by adding a comma like this:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * from sites WHERE site = ?)", (site,))
```

But, if your version of SQLite is 3.24.0+, you should consider taking a different approach by choosing [`UPSERT`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html) as the method to do what you want.
You want to insert a new row if the `site` value does not exist in the table or update the existing row if it does exist.

So, assuming there is already a unique constraint for the column `site`, you can do it more efficiently with:

```
sql = """
INSERT into sites values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
ON CONFLICT(site) DO UPDATE SET
cur_ip = EXCLUDED.cur_ip, cur_rank = EXCLUDED.cur_rank, cur_hash = EXCLUDED.cur_hash
"""
cursor.execute(sql, (site,cur_ip,None,cur_rank,None,None,cur_hash,None))
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I do have a unique constraint on it, I know I should.
Only issue I have with the second answer or should I say question is this would not update if the information was there correct?

Comment: @Pittsie UPSERT inserts a new row but if there is a conflict of a unique constraint it does not insert and updates the existing row.

Comment: sorry for the delayed response but that sounds perfect for what I need as well as quick and easy. I'm all about quick and easy